# texture with internal format GL_RGBA8 turns up in fragment shader as float

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, render-to-texture

I have created a texture with this call:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

I render to the texture with a dark grey color:

```
glColor3ub(42, 42, 42);
glBegin()...
```

Now I render this texture to the backbuffer using a custom shader. In the fragment I access the texture like this:

```
#version 130
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : require
uniform usampler2D text_in;
```

and get the data using:

```
uvec4 f0 = texture(text_in, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
```

I would expect the value in `f0[0]` to be `42u`, but it is `1042852009u`, which happens to be

```
float x = 42/255.0f;
unsigned i = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);
```

What am I doing wrong? I would like to work with integer textures, so that I in the fragment shader can compare a pixel value to an exact integer value. I know that the render-to-textures works well, because if I render the texture to the backbuffer without the custom shader, I get 42-grey as expected.

Answer (score 3):

An `RGBA8` format is an unsigned, [normalized](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Normalized_Integer) format. When you read from/write to it, it is therefore treated as if it were a floating point format, whose values are restricted to the [0, 1] range. Normalized values are basically just compressed floats.

If you want an [unsigned *integer* format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format), you're looking for `GL_RGBA8UI`. Note that you also must use `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` in the [pixel transfer format field](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format) when using `glTexImage2D`.

Comment: ... and the texture is all transparant.

Comment: `glCheckFramebufferStatus` does not report any errors.

Comment: `glClearColor(0,1,0,1);glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` actually clears the texture to `[0,255,0,255]` as expected, but `glColor3ub` + `glBegin...` doesn't modify the texture.

Comment: now it works. I also needed a custom fragment shader to render to the integer texture. But I still don't know how the color set by `glColor` can be accessed from inside the shader, so I use `glGetUniformLocation` and `glUniform4ui` to set the color.

Comment: @XPlatformer: "*I still don't know how the color set by glColor can be accessed from inside the shader*" If you're using features like integer textures, then it's time to leave the world of compatibility GL behind (things like `glBegin/glColor`) and write core OpenGL stuff.